# Storing multiple values to array and retrieving it in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am writing a code to create a cart, each product has multiple properties like front, back, sleeve etc

Each time user clicks on product he has multiple properties to choose from, once user chooses a product with all the properties he will go to order summary (CART PAGE) page where he will see his selected product with an option to add more product or delete the present product and there he can checkout.

Now I am saving the product to session variable for showing it on cart page.
but getting an error warning,

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'oid'

please guide me to the correct form of using multidimensional array to storing the product properties and price with it in session which can be retrieved on cart page to show to the user.

I am trying below code

for Creating array

```
  <?php
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $front = $_POST['front_select'];
    $back = $_POST['back_select'];
    $side = $_POST['side_select'];
    $oid = $_POST['orderID'];
    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $cart = array (
    'oid' => $oid,
    'front' => $front,
    'back' => $back
    );

    $_SESSION['cart'][] = $cart;


}
?>
```

FOR RETRIEVING

```
  if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
                    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) { ?>
    <h5>ORDER ID : <b id="oid">#<?php echo   $item['oid'];  ?></b> | ORDER TYPE : <b id="product_type">BLOUSE</b> | PRODUCT ID : <b id="product_id"></b></h5>
    <?php ))?>
```

Please help me I am new to PHP

Comment: What's the warning? have you started the session while retrieving?

Comment: `but getting an error warning`. are you wanting us to guess what the error message is, instead of having us focus on how to help? It would be helpful to us if you post the error message as well.

Comment: is there a reason you are getting `$_POST['side_select']` && `$_POST['pid']`, but not adding them to the `$cart` array? Also, in your `foreach()`, you will have `count($_SESSION['cart'])` number of `id="oid"`, which will cause you headaches if you ever need to reference the `id`. You either want `class="oid"` or create unique id's, ie `id="oid<?php echo   $item['oid'];  ?>"`

Comment: That error message tells you that you have at least 1 `$_SESSION['cart']` that does not have a `oid` key. Do a `print_r($_SESSION['cart']);` or `var_dump($_SESSION['cart']);` before your `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item)` to see what is in your `$_SESSION['cart']` cart array. You could also do a `if(isset($item['oid'])){` after  `foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item)` to only print the rows that are valid.

Comment: @Matt Still getting same warning

Comment: @Matt removing the `[]` at the end of `$_SESSION['cart'][]` would cause the new row to overwrite the last row, and it would only contain 1 row, instead of many, which defeats the purpose of having a cart. That would be like going to a supermarket, where you could only buy the 1 item in you hand, and not be able to get a cart and put many items in.

Comment: Thanks it works for me @Sean

Comment: So did you find an invalid `$_SESSION['cart']` row? Do you have code somewhere that is adding a row to `$_SESSION['cart']` without a `oid` key? Or is the error happening when `$_SESSION['cart']` is empty, after you have `$_SESSION['cart']=array()`, but before you have added any rows in the `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`?